# Is it "$\Rightarrow$" or "$\Leftarrow$" in "$x^2 = 9 \text{ ? } x = 3$"?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

The equation $x^2 = 9$ has the solution set {-3,3}, that is $(x = -3 \vee x = 3)$. So I would understand that
$$
x^2 = 9 \iff (x = -3 \vee x = 3)
$$
Now "usually" (perhaps) one writes in course of solving an equation
$$ \dots\quad x^2 = 9 \Rightarrow x = 3  $$
but I think that is wrong, because a set implies a "larger" or equal set, So the correct one should read
$$  x^2 = 9 \Leftarrow x = 3  $$
So which one is correct ?

Comment: People usually write $x^2=9 \implies x=3$ in case when $x$ represents some length in geometry or has a strict condition that it has to be positive.

Comment: This is weird because the latter is logically correct, but do not lead to a conclusion (in solving an equation).

Comment: should I close the question because the answer and the comments do not add anything new, it confirmed the obvious only

Comment: Well, you only asked about "the obvious"... You claim that people usually write $x^2 = 9 \implies x = 3$, the simple explanation is that many people unfortunately do not understand how $\implies$ and $\impliedby$ works (or it was assumed that $x$ is positive). Fortunately, at a certain level, such mistakes at not made anymore.

Answer (score 3):

To begin with, $x^2=9 \Leftarrow x=3$ is certainly correct.

Regarding the other way around, $x^2=9 \Rightarrow x=3$ it depends. If $x$ earlier has been restricted to be non-negative, e.g. if $x \in \mathbb{N}$, then the implication is correct. If $x$ can be negative, the implication is not correct, since also $x=-3$ is a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^2=9\Rightarrow x=3$$ is wrong.

Try $x=-3.$
$$x=3\Rightarrow x^2=9$$ is true of course.

Also $x^2=9$ is equivalent to $x=3$ or $x=-3$ because $x^2-9=(x-3)(x+3).$

Comment: I thought about that, but I think when some one writes the first implication, one has usualy in mind other assumptions beside $x^2 =9$, sth like $x>0$

Comment: @Physor  We just need to use the definitions of equivalation and implication. $x>0$ does not change something. For $x>0$ we see that $x=-3\Rightarrow x^2=9$ is true and it's true for any real value of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2 = 9 \iff x^2 - 9 = 0$ is clear. Of course $x^2 -9 = (x-3)(x+3)$, and in all fields (like $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$) we have that $$ab= 0 \iff (a = 0) \lor (b=0)\tag{1}$$ for all $a,b$ in that field.

So $$x^2 = 9 \iff (x-3)(x+3)= 0 \iff (x-3 = 0) \lor (x+3=0) \iff x=3 \lor x= -3$$

So every step is reversible by standard facts about inverses and $(1)$.